# Calculating the value of integers in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with `int` values that I would like to add to each other and log the end value. So far I could create a working solution, but it's not so elegant and I would be happy if somebody could show me a smarter solution to achieve the same result.

```
numberList  = (list(string_dict.values()))
numz = []
placeholder = 0

for x in numberList:
    numz.append(int(x))

for y in numz:
    placeholder = placeholder + y
print (placeholder)

# [1,2,3]   
# result: 6
```

Comment: If they're integers, why are you converting `x` with `int(x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take out both loops by using the [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) functions:

```
numberList  = list(string_dict.values())
numz = []
placeholder = 0

numz = list(map(int, numberList))

placeholder = sum(numz)
print (placeholder)
```

You don't really need to have `numberList` and `numz` in there, though.  Just do this:

```
placeholder = sum(map(int, string_dict.values()))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `sum` function:

```
print(sum(int(x) for x in string_dict.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function also:

```
from functools import reduce

print reduce( (lambda x, y: x + y), string_dict.values() )
```

Comment: Won't that create a string?

Comment: No it will be int only.